# Create list of files from a source folder

Tags: autoit

Please help me on how to create a list, possibly from an arrayList. An input box is the source of the folder and all its png files will be in the list of array, and display it in the GU. Thanks

```
#include <GuiConstantsEx.au3>
#include <File.au3>
#include <Array.au3>

;GUI
GUICreate("Automation", 300, 500)
$sourceFolder = GUICtrlCreateInput ("Source Folder" , 10, 10,280, 20 )
$add = GUICtrlCreateButton("Add", 10, 35, 75, 20)
$mylist = GUICtrlCreateList("", 10, 60, 280, 300)

$sourceFolder = ControlGetText("Automation", "", "Edit1")
Local $FileList = _FileListToArray($sourceFolder, "*.png")


    $msg = 0
    While $msg 
        $msg = GUIGetMsg()
        Select
            Case $msg = $add
                GUICtrlSetData($mylist,$FileList)
                Exit
        EndSelect
    WEnd

If $sourceFolder > 1 Then
   If @error = 1 Then
       MsgBox(0, "", "No Folders Found.")
       Exit
   EndIf
   If @error = 4 Then
       MsgBox(0, "", "No Files Found.")
       Exit
   EndIf
   $arrayFileList = _ArrayDisplay($FileList)
EndIf



; GUI MESSAGE LOOP
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)
While 1
    Switch GUIGetMsg()
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            Exit

    EndSwitch
WEnd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of problems in your code.

- 2 message loops is very bad practice
- The first message loop never starts, because you have `While $msg`, and set `$msg` to `0` the line before.
- You are reading the source folder control before the first message loop, so it's value will always be `"Source Folder"` rather than the directory like you want.
- Even if the first message loop did run, the GUI wouldn't be shown yet.

In terms of what you want to do: it's just a For...Next loop over the returned array.

```
#include <GuiConstantsEx.au3>
#include <File.au3>
#include <Array.au3>

;GUI
GUICreate("Automation", 300, 500)
$sourceFolder = GUICtrlCreateInput("Source Folder", 10, 10, 280, 20)
$add = GUICtrlCreateButton("Add", 10, 35, 75, 20)
$mylist = GUICtrlCreateList("", 10, 60, 280, 300)


GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)

While 1
    $msg = GUIGetMsg()
    Switch $msg
        Case $add
            $sFolder = ControlGetText("Automation", "", "Edit1")
            Local $FileList = _FileListToArray($sFolder, "*.*")

            If @error = 1 Then
                MsgBox(0, "", "No Folders Found.")
                Exit
            EndIf
            If @error = 4 Then
                MsgBox(0, "", "No Files Found.")
                Exit
            EndIf

            For $i = 1 To $FileList[0]
                GUICtrlSetData($mylist, $FileList[$i])
            Next
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            ExitLoop
    EndSwitch
WEnd
```